# Do these two systems of differential equations both describe the motion of the elastic pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, differential-equations

The [elastic pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_pendulum) is a chaotic dynamical system which is equivalent to a mass attached to a string in 2 or 3 dimensions. It exhibits complex harmonic motion and chaotic behavior. Wikipedia gives a system in two variables (distance from the fixed point $x$ and angle from the fixed point $y$) that describe the motion of the mass, which were derived using the Lagrangian. [This website](https://www.myphysicslab.com/springs/2d-spring-en.html) gives an interactive demo with a similar system of 2 equations, derived using Newtonian mechanics. I am making a similar simulation for a website, and I could only get the second equations to
produce a reasonable result when RK4 integration was used. I would like to know if these two equations are describing the same dynamical system.

Comment: The two sets of equations are not immediately equivalent since the myPhysicsLab version includes damping which the Wikipedia version does not. However, if you set the damping constant $b$ to zero in the myPhysicsLab version, they should become equivalent, although one is in polar co-ordinates and the other is in cartesian co-ordinates.

Comment: Voting to reopen - the question is perfectly clear.

Comment: The equations of motion are not equal, because the generalized coordinates are not equal, but the numerical simulation must be equal , if you obtain the damping equal zero

Comment: What you mean by second equations ?

Comment: @gandalf61 - Thank you, I was planning to do it without damping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Newton EOM's**

with the position vector to the mass

$$\mathbf P= \left[ \begin {array}{c} x\\  y\end {array} \right]\quad\Rightarrow\quad,
\mathbf P_N=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,\mathbf P 
$$

where $~x~,y~$ are the generalized coordinates

thus:
$$m\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \ddot{x} \\
  \ddot{y} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf F_g+\mathbf F_s\tag 1$$

with gravitation force :
$$\mathbf F_g= -m\,g\,\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and the spring force

$$\mathbf F_s=-k\,s\,\mathbf P_N=-k\,(\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}-L)\,\mathbf P_N$$
where $~s~$ is the spring deflection and $~L~$ is the initial spring length.

you obtain with equation (1)

$$ m{\ddot x}-{\frac {k \left( -\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}+L \right) x}{
\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}}}
=0\\
m{\ddot y}+mg-{\frac {k \left( -\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}+L \right) 
y}{\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}}}
=0
$$

with  damper force in equation (1)
$$\mathbf F_d=-d\,\dot s\,\mathbf P_N\\
\dot s=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,(x\,\dot x+y\,\dot y)$$

to compare the numerical simulation results , you have to „adapt“ the initial condition. $~x(0)=x_0~,y(0)=y_0~$

with the initial condition, $ ~s(0)=0~,\dot s(0)=0~$
and the angle $~\phi(0)=\phi_0~, \dot\phi(0)=0~\Rightarrow$
$$x_0=L\,\sin(\phi_0)~,y_0=L\,\cos(\phi_0)$$

[image]